# CPU section in vmstat

Tags: vmstat

The man page for `vmstat` states, for example for wa section, " time spent waiting for IO" but what is the unit of time? Is it in seconds?

Comment: On my system, that section of the man page is prefaced with `These are percentages of total CPU time.`

Answer (score 0):

Read the whole man page:

```
  CPU
       These are percentages of total CPU time.
       us: Time spent running non-kernel code.  (user time, including nice time)
       sy: Time spent running kernel code.  (system time)
       id: Time spent idle.  Prior to Linux 2.5.41, this includes IO-wait time.
       wa: Time spent waiting for IO.  Prior to Linux 2.5.41, included in idle.
       st: Time stolen from a virtual machine.  Prior to Linux 2.6.11, unknown.
```

These are all percentages of the total CPU time.